# NSManagedObjectContext.performBlockAndWait() runs the block on main thread/queue

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, core-data, concurrency

```
print("queue1: \(NSOperationQueue.currentQueue())")
managedObjectContext.performBlockAndWait({
    print("queue2: \(NSOperationQueue.currentQueue())")
})
```

and output is:

```
queue1: Optional(<NSOperationQueue: 0x7fa31c030cf0>{name = 'NSOperationQueue 0x7fa31c030cf0'})
queue2: Optional(<NSOperationQueue: 0x7fa319d114d0>{name = 'NSOperationQueue Main Queue'})
```

So, `performBlockAndWait` runs the block in main thread. Don't know why?
Is this the expected behaviour?

So, any solutions for the problems:

1. I need to run the code of the block in background, else it freezes UI. So, how can I?, **or**
2. If I don't use `performBlockAndWait` the code in the block crash with the description `Terminating app due to uncaught exception NSInvalidArgumentException, reason _referenceData64 only defined for abstract class`. Any alternative?

Comment: The whole point of `performBlockAndWait` **is that it waits**. Even if it ran the block on a different thread, the code that calls `performBlockAndWait` would still **wait** until the block finished-- meaning that your UI would **still** stop responding while it was in progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PerformBlock() and performBlockAndWait() runs on the queue in which your context is created. So if your managedObjectContext is created in main queue it will run in the main queue.

If you want background execution you need to create a background context :

```
let privateContext = NSManagedObjectContext(
  concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)

privateContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = mainQueueContext.persistentStoreCoordinator

privateContext.performBlock {
...
}
```

Comment: And should I use single 'managedObjectContext' in the whole app, or can I create whenever they required ?

Comment: A single mainqueue managedObjectContext will be enough for most cases. You can create a new background context if you have a lot of data e.g to insert into core data and can't block the ui.

Answer (score -1):

Perform your task you want to do in background in a separate function with a completion handler.

```
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
        func performFuncWithCompletion() { (Success) in
              if (Success)
                  NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
                      // update UI here
                  }
               else {  
                       // Show error message?
                    }
           }  
  }


 func performFuncWithCompletion(completion : (SuccessStatus: Bool)) {
        // perform your back ground function here.
        // Decide if everything went fine
       if everythingWentFine {
           completion(true)
        }
       else {
            completion(false)
            }
}
```

Ask if any questions

Comment: Yeah, I tried that also. But encountered the exception above (in point 2 of the question)

Comment: What exception and on what line?

Comment: The one - Terminating app due to uncaught exception NSInvalidArgumentException, reason _referenceData64 only defined for abstract class

Comment: And the line number is variable with each crash, but when some field of the entity is set, (e.g entity.field = "a").

Comment: managedObjectContext has run run on the same thread it was created according to applesDoc